# WSO2 API Manager - java code sample to connect WSO2 API manager to do TOKEN API operations like generate production keys, tokens, refresh tokens etc

Tags: api, wso2, token

Currently I am doing POC on WSO2 API Manager. Is there any java client code sample to connect WSO2 API manager to do TOKEN API operations like generate production keys, tokens, refresh tokens etc.

Answer (score 0):

For tokens, you can use token services 
https://docs.wso2.com/m/mobile.action#page/92520179

they are supporting default OAuth 2.0 protocol

For the client registration there are client-registration services

https://wso2.com/blogs/cloud/apis-to-control-your-api-management/

I know the last link is for wso2 cloud, but the services are same or similar on the product, you may google a little to find version you need

You asked for java code, but these services are exposed as simple rest services so may use http calls to invoke them